# Encrypting Src of Iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, encryption

I own a website. There are some movies on the website, which are made by myself. I want to make money from the website by creating paid movies. That means the website visitor need to pay to watch the full movie or to download the movie.

In the website, the movies are played in an Iframe now. My idea is to upload the paid movies into a directory. The directory's name is as complex as a password. Then I will hide the name of the directory so the website visitors cannot download or watch the paid movies without going into my Iframe.

I have already used javascript to prevent right click "Open in new tab" and "Open in new window". I want to know how can I encrypt the Src of the Iframe so that the website visitors will not know anything just by watching the source code.

Please use PHP or CSS or HTML of JAVASCRIPT to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is a very general question.  Can you provide any code that shows what you have tried to this point?

Comment: Not possible, the browser needs to know the url in order to open it, this is trivial for any one to see (F12 > Network Inspector for example)  You would need to implement some kind of authentication scheme/user registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone will be able to look up the videos real url using the network inspector / console. The only way to really protect your videos from being watched from unauthorised people would be setting up an appropriate pay wall / authentication scheme.

Answer (score 0):

[Encrypted Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/) is the standard you're looking for.

It will not do what you asked, but is the solution for you.